# Bad request Error while i send parameters through url query string in flask

Tags: python, flask, runtime-error

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/calc",methods=['GET'])
def calc():
    arg=request.args
    res=eval(arg["value1"]+arg["value3"]+arg["value2"])
    return res
```

This is my code and getting bad request.

I'm passing the following query string along with url calc: `value1=5&value2=4&operation=+`

Output: 9

Comment: Why are you querying "value1=5&value2=4&operation=+" and not "value1=5&value2=4&value3=1"?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `+` differently.

Either you need to urlencode it, or you need to send a placeholder, e.g. `plus` and then map it to a "real" plus sign.

Also, you variable names are mixed up. One time you name it values, one time operation.

Another problem is your call to eval - you hardcode the plus sign.

This all said, if you ever want to publish your app on the internet, you have to make sure that nobody can enter bad input. So you need to make sure that e.g. `value1` is really a number, and not a command which gets executed by your `eval` call.